# How to add aria-label in @Html.RadioButtonFor in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

In my MVC razor view I am using `@Html.RadioButtonFor`. I want to use aria-label for screen reader but not sure how to use it.

If I add `aria-label` then I get `The name 'aria' does not exist in current context` error.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(options => options.SelectedFulfillmentType, option, new { id = id, required = "required", @class = option.GetDisplayName().ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") + "-input", aria-label = "Test"})
```

If I add `aria_label` then I do not get any error but I do not see that tag on browser.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(options => options.SelectedFulfillmentType, option, new { id = id, required = "required", @class = option.GetDisplayName().ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") + "-input", aria_label = "Test"})
```

Comment: `aria_label` is working for me see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KDuZMY

Comment: @AshleyMedway You are right. I didn't see `else` part of the logic. Sorry about that.